# How can i set the bot's status (Not activity, custom status) Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, status

I'm trying to do a selfbot and I wanna do a custom status command, is there any way to do it on discord.py? if so let me know

code of what I've tried:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

user = commands.Bot(command_prefix="user!")

@user.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online")
    await user.change_presence(status="Hey!")

    
user.run("BotToken")
```

Comment: Activity and status are basically the same thing. Are you looking for 1. online, idle, do not disturb; or 2. playing [whatever]; or 3. a full rich presence? Also can you include the code that you've tried?

Comment: I'm trying to set the custom status, not the normal status the one that includes text, but recreated in the bot

image of what i mean: https://freeimage.host/i/V1H2se

Comment: It's not possible: https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1160

Answer (score 0):

hope this is what you are looking for:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="'en' prefix!"))
    print("Enfloo Bot is Ready and Online")
```

You can change status to change that green circle, for example 'idle' and change ActivityType to change 'Listening to' into 'Watching' or 'Playing' for example. Comment if you needed anything else.

This is how to change the status. I do not think it possible to change it into a custom one not beginning with something like: 'Listening to'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
# Setting `Playing ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="a game"))

# Setting `Streaming ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url=my_twitch_url))

# Setting `Listening ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))

# Setting `Watching ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))
```